# Missing ) after argument but only for a long string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JavaScript to fill a `<div>` tag with other `<div>`s. It has been working until I changed an identifier used inside a onclick event. The old identifier (index) was just a small number from 0-1000, but the new identifier (id) is a uuid.v4() generated string that looks like this:

```
f5ec8170-e75c-4a93-9997-1a683b7d2e00
```

I have the exact same code for index and the id. But whenever I click on the button which is suppose to activate the function call with the id as an argument it gives me:

> Missing ) after argument

Which does not happen when I click on the button which does the same thing with index as an argument instead of id.

My code:

```
var id = messages[i].id;
var index = 0;

var newElement =
                                '<div class="fullMessage" id="fullRightMessage' + i + '">'+
                                    '<h6 class="textMessage">' + messages[i].comment + '</h6>' +
                                    '<button class="likeButtonMessage" onclick="likeClicked(right, ' + index + ', 1);">LIKE</button>' +
                                    '<button class="dislikeButtonMessage" onclick="likeClicked(right, ' + id + ', -1);">DIS</button>' +
                                    '<h4 id="scoreright' + i + '" class="messageScore">' + messages[i].score + '</h4>' +
                                '</div>'
```

Comment: You need to pass `string`  i.e. `id` in quotes like `'<button  onclick="likeClicked(right, \'' + index + '\', 1);">LIKE</button>' `,

Comment: @Satpal typo?  id, not index and that will generate bad html - you need to escape an apostrophe, not add double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not enclose the uuid with quotation marks. Before it worked because your id was a clean integer which doesn't need them.

Exchange the line with id to

```
'<button class="dislikeButtonMessage" onclick="likeClicked(right, \'' + id + '\', -1);">DIS</button>' +
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous ID was interpreted as an `int`, which is the reason why it worked.

Your new ID is a `string`, requiring you to enclose it in quotation marks:

```
onclick="likeClicked(right, \'' + id + '\', -1);"
```

This is because this is *not* valid code:

```
likeClicked(right, f5ec8170-e75c-4a93-9997-1a683b7d2e00, -1)
```